# MySQL JDBC force ignore client certificate on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-web-services, java

I have a Java web app running on AWS and connecting to a MySQL database running on AWS RDS.

My app uses SSL client certificates signed by our own CA to connect to various web services, so I have set the `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` system properties.

I have added the `https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` certificates to my `trustStore`, and I can connect to MySQL fine using SSL via the command-line client.

My MySQL connection string looks like:

```
jdbc:mysql://my-server-id.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/my-database?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

I am using `mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.38` to run the JBDC connection.

I have found that my Java app can connect OK to MySQL when I set the `trustStore`, but it fails when I set the `keyStore` and the `trustStore`:

```
! javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
! at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkRecordVersion(InputRecord.java:552) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
! at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:565) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
! at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
! at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
! at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
! at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
! at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
! at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:149) ~[user-portal-web-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
! ... 40 common frames omitted
```

It seems that Java is presenting my private-CA signed client cert to MySQL, which is rejecting it. I have captured the interaction using `tcpdump`, and the DN of my client cert is being sent to MySQL.

How can I use my client cert for HTTPS connections, but not use it for the MySQL connection?

I have tried creating an empty keystore and setting my connection string to use it:

```
jdbc:mysql://my-server-id.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/my-database?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:nokeys.jks&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=changeit
```

That gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TrustManagerFactoryImpl is not initialized
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineGetTrustManagers(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(TrustManagerFactory.java:285)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.getSSLSocketFactoryDefaultOrConfigured(ExportControlled.java:323)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:85)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force MySQL to use no client certificate by setting an empty keystore in the connection URL.

The problem I had above was a variant of https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36948 -- if you set "clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl" in the connection URL but not also "trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl" (and the 4 other params below), then MySQL will crash with "TrustManagerFactoryImpl is not initialized" instead of a more helpful error.

You can create an empty keystore with a command like:

```
keytool -genkey -alias foo -keystore empty.jks # (set password "changeit")
keytool -delete -alias foo -keystore empty.jks
```

Then connect to MySQL with a URL like:

```
jdbc:mysql://my-server-id.rds.amazonaws.com/my-database?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:empty.jks&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=changeit&clientCertificateKeyStoreType=JKS&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/etc/pki/cosmos/current/client.jks&trustCertificateKeyStoreType=JKS&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=changeit
```

All 6 keystore args are required, even if you want the defaults, otherwise you will see the "TrustManagerFactoryImpl is not initialized" error

Comment: Additionally, you can just leave off the 3 clientCertificate... params from the JDBC URL and it also connects. This is with version `5.1.40`. It solves the infamous `SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0`.